# How do I get NSubstitute mocks to fail when the arguments don't match the given pattern?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, nsubstitute

I'm responsible for the testing of a legacy software developed in C and C# that my team is maintaining. The original team used NSubstitute 3.1 to create test doubles for delegates in order to perform unit test of the APIs for the C# sections. Here's one such test double, where irrelevant details have been omitted:

```
private static byte[] MockSelectByAidWithoutData(ushort retVal)
{
    var expectedIn= "FFFEFDFCFB".HexToBytes();
    var expectedOut= "010203040506070809".HexToBytes();

    var fake = Substitute.For<SomeDelegate>();
    fake(Arg.Is<byte[]>(x => expectedIn.SequenceEqual(x.Take(expectedIn.Length))),
            Arg.Is(0x00),
            Arg.Is(expectedIn.Length),
            Arg.Any<int>(),
            Arg.Any<int>(),
            out int outputLength)
        .Returns(x =>
            {
                expectedOut.CopyTo((Array)x[0], 0);
                x[5] = expectedOut.Length;
                return retVal;
            }
        );
    Mediator.GetInstance().Delegate = fake;
    return expectedOut;
}
```

Now, if the fake delegate is invoked with arguments that match what is specified in the `fake()` call, it returns the `retVal` value and everybody is happy. However, if some value won't match, it returns zero. Since zero is a valid but incorrect value, the execution continues and I get an error that is not the root cause of the issue I am testing (i.e. bad output when the problem is actually bad input)

I am looking for a way to either:

- specify a "catch all" behaviour for the values that won't match the expectations, or
- get an exception if the arguments don't match the expectation

so that the test case would fail immediately upon reception of the wrong input with a meaningful message and without triggering further behaviour that would just pollute the outcome of the test.

Thanks in advance,

DeK

P.S. I can probably switch safely to a more recent version of NSubstitute if that's really necessary.

Comment: I think you'd need to use `Received` to assert a call was made with specific arguments. If this is going to duplicate logic from the `Returns` stub you could potentially switch that with `ReturnsForAnyArgs` and only match arguments in the `Received` assertion.

Comment: That's similar to to the workaround I'm using, I just accept Any argument in the call to fake() and then manually do all the asserting inside a callback using AndDoes. 
(The Received part would never be executed because the retval = 0 triggers an Exception.)
However I don't really like the workaround: I'm manually doing what the framework should do for me. Seems like I'm just stuck with the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> specify a "catch all" behaviour for the values that won't match the expectations

I think I've found a way you can do this. If you first stub the "catch all" / failure case for all arguments, you can then stub more specific calls. NSubstitute will try to match the most recent specifications provided, falling back to earlier stubbed values.

Here is a sample.

*Note it is using [`Configure`](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/configure/) from `NSubstitute.Extensions` namespace introduced in NSubstitute 4.x. This isn't strictly necessary because NSubstitute will automatically assume you are configuring a call if you are using argument matchers, but it is a good pattern to use when configuring overlapping calls like this.*

```
using NSubstitute;
using NSubstitute.Extensions; // required for Configure()

public class Thing {
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public interface ISample {
    int Example(Thing a, string b);
}

public class UnexpectedCallException : Exception { }

[Fact]
public void ExampleOfStubOneCallButFailOthers() {
    var sub = Substitute.For<ISample>();

    // Catch all case:
    sub.Example(null, null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(x => throw new UnexpectedCallException());

    // Specific case. We use Configure from NSubstitute.Extensions to
    // be able to stub this without getting an UnexpectedCallException.
    // Not strictly necessary here as we're using argument matchers so NSub
    // already knows we're configuring a call, but it's a good habit to get into.
    // See: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/configure/
    sub.Configure()
        .Example(Arg.Is<Thing>(x => x.Id == "abc"), Arg.Any<string>())
        .Returns(x => 42);

    // Example of non-matching call:
    Assert.Throws<UnexpectedCallException>(() =>
        sub.Example(new Thing { Id = "def" }, "hi")
    );

    // Example of matching call:
    Assert.Equal(42, sub.Example(new Thing { Id = "abc" }, "hello"));
}
```

You could extend this to include information about arguments that do not match, but that will be a bit of custom work. If you look at some of NSubstitute's argument formatting code that might be re-usable to help with this.

---

*Update to include delegate example*

I just ran this with a delegate instead and it also passes:

```
public delegate int SomeDelegate(Thing a, string b);

[Fact]
public void ExampleOfStubOneDelegateCallButFailOthers() {
    var sub = Substitute.For<SomeDelegate>();
    sub(null, null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(x => throw new UnexpectedCallException());
    sub.Configure()
        .Invoke(Arg.Is<Thing>(x => x.Id == "abc"), Arg.Any<string>())
        .Returns(x => 42);
    Assert.Throws<UnexpectedCallException>(() => sub(new Thing { Id = "def" }, "hi"));
    Assert.Equal(42, sub(new Thing { Id = "abc" }, "hello"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I was talking about, however it doesn't seem to work for delegates, or even supposed to work since the Configure() method only exists at the interface/class level.

Comment: @DekDekku I updated the answer with a delegate example that seems to work ok. Can you describe the error/behaviour you're seeing with the delegate example?

Comment: Thanks again. As I said, the Configure() method was just not available on the fake object. I'll try again, since I was updating from v3.1 and perhaps Intellisense needs a little more time to refresh.

Comment: Awww, scraps! I was not using the Extensions package. That was it. Please, add this detail on top of your answer, even tho' it's specified in the code example, to make it clearer for anybody else having the same issue!

Comment: Sorry about that! I've added the `using` statements to the top of the code sample. Do you think that's sufficient?

Comment: Perfect! That's a new feature of v4 therefore it was missing in my project (just writing this to get the required amount of characters...)

Comment: `Configure()` isn't strictly required in this case. NSubstitute will assume you are configuring a call if you have used argument matchers. So this should work in v3 without the `Configure()` call. (I've added a note on this in the answer.) Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: It should, indeed, work for the delegate too, at least there is nothing forbidding it in the docs. But it doesn't. It only accepted "normal" function calls after the first one (even after I switched to v4)